# is there 'indexed but not stored' field in sphinx?

Tags: sphinx

I'm trying to found a field defination like Solr's 'indexed but not stored'. http://sphinxsearch.com/wiki/doku.php?id=fields_and_attributes, by the document, sphinx has not defined such field. Is there anyway to reach this?

Answer (score 1):

`Fields` ARE "indexed but not stored". They are the staple of full-text searching. A column is automatically a field unless made an attribute.

`Attributes` on the other hand, are stored - but not 'indexed' as such.